# how to show alert on session_start

Tags: c#, session

I need to show an alert in C# webforms using global.asax in session_start method. It's just for one time when the user gets on to the application.

I have this piece of code in session_Start, and I am not getting any alert.

```
string cleanMessage = msg.Replace("'", "\'"); 
string script = "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('" + cleanMessage +
                                                      "');</script>"; 

Page page = HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler as Page;
page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(string), "alert", script);
```

Please let me know what am i doing wrong, or is this even possible.

Thanks,
Nihir

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [RegisterStartupScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/asz8zsxy.aspx) instead.  [This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478975.aspx) should give you plenty of info.  However I have the feeling you need to crystallise your knowledge in what runs client / server side.

Comment: I am still not able to figure out. Still it doesn't alert on page load.

Comment: Check the HTML / Javascript **as it appears in your browser**.  We'll be able to tell you why then

Answer (score 0):

What you could is modify your code a bit to store the script in a session variable, then if all of your pages inherit from a base class that inherits from Page you could add move your RegisterClientScriptBlock into the Page_load event of the base class and only run if the Session variable is not null.  Hope that helps.